# move_uploaded_file Error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php

I have a simple function that allows me to upload files to a server. These files get stored into a folder and the path is written into the database. In the function there is a if statement that checks what sort of file a user is trying to upload, files that are allowed to bee uploaded are torrents and other Microsoft office files (docx, pptx...). when uploading certain files I sometimes get a error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null. I tested if the upload function with two different pptx files one was uploaded successfully the other threw the error. I don't know how to fix the error since some files are getting uploaded successful and others are giving me the error. There is the function that is giving me problems. I tested the code and from what I saw the tmp_name sometimes doesn't get a value (it is empty)

```php
function dodajTorrent($kategorije) {
            if (isset($_POST['gumb'])) {
                $link = open_database_connection();
                $vseKategorije=serialize($kategorije);
                $naslov = $_POST['naslov'];
                $vsebina = $_POST['vsebina'];
                $kategorija = $_POST['kategorija'];
                $file = $_FILES['file'];
                $filename = $file['name'];
                $extention = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        
                if (empty($naslov) || empty($vsebina) || $kategorija==0) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("You left empty fields!") </script>';
                } else {
                    if ($extention != "torrent" && $extention != "docx" && $extention != "doc" && $extention != "rft" && $extention != "xls" && $extention != "xlsx" && $extention!= "ppt" && $extention!= "pptx" && $extention != "pdf" && $extention != "7z" && $extention != "zip" && $extention != "rar") {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error uploading file: ' . $extention . '") </script>';
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT NASLOV FROM Torrenti WHERE NASLOV = '$naslov'";
                        $rezultat = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                        $st_vrstic = mysqli_num_rows($rezultat);
            
                        if ($st_vrstic == 1) {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Torrent already exists!") </script>';
                        } else {
                            $torrentDatoteka = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
                            $file123 = "files/" . $torrentDatoteka;
                            $fileFullPath = "/var/www/html/torrent-tracker/files/" . $torrentDatoteka;
            
                            if (file_exists($fileFullPath)) {
                                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("File already exists!") </script>';
                            } else {
                                if ($st_vrstic == 0) {
                                    $username = $_SESSION['uporabnik'];
            
                                    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM Blinker_IP WHERE UPORABNIK='$username'";
                                    $rezultat = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                    $vrstica = mysqli_fetch_row($rezultat);
                                    $id_uporabnika = $vrstica[0];
                                    
                                    $path = "/var/www/html/torrent-tracker/files";
                                    $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
                                    $name = basename($torrentDatoteka);
    
                                    $sqlID="SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Torrenti";
                                    $rezultat = mysqli_query($link, $sqlID);
                                    $vrstica=mysqli_fetch_row($rezultat);
                                    $IdNovegaTorrenta=$vrstica[0]+1;
    
    
                                    $vsebinaPoti = "VsebineTorrentov/" . $IdNovegaTorrenta . ".txt";
                                    file_put_contents($vsebinaPoti, $_POST['vsebina']);
            
                                    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
                                        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$path/$name")) {
                                            echo "File moved successfully";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "File move failed: " . error_get_last()["message"] ."<br>";
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo "file not mooved";
                                    }
                                    
            
                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO Torrenti (NASLOV, VSEBINA, ID_UP, DATOTEKA, KATEGORIJA, ŽANR) VALUES ('$naslov', '$vsebinaPoti', '$id_uporabnika', '$file123', '$kategorija', '$vseKategorije')";
                                    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            
                                    $location = (vrniRang() == 1) ? "index.php?stran=admin_main" : "index.php?stran=mod_main";
                                    var_dump($_FILES);
                                    header("Location: " . $location);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

File move failed: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

array(1) { ["file"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(11) "MotoGP.pptx" ["full_path"]=> string(11) "MotoGP.pptx" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: Don't use all those nested `else { if`. Use `elseif` so they stay at the same level of nesting. It makes the code much easier to read.

Comment: What does `var_dump($file)` show?

Comment: Better yet, what does `var_dump($_FILES)` show?

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) = array(1) { ["file"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(11) "MotoGP.pptx" ["full_path"]=> string(11) "MotoGP.pptx" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } } for pptx file

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting this error in that case.

Comment: BTW, you should use `$tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];`.

Comment: You should add code that checks that there's a file: `if (isset($_FILES['file']))` before trying to process the upload.

Comment: added the if statement. the file is detected every  time

Comment: Then this error is simply not possible. If it says that `$_FILES['file']` exists, it won't be null.

Comment: I dont know how else i could show you

Comment: Please update the question with the current code that has that check, and post the complete error message.

Comment: Try to check [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: already did increased it to 20M

Comment: Re your updated post: `["error"]=> int(1)`... any value except 0 in this field means the upload failed for some reason. Error 1 means The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php. Your code _must_ check the value of `$_FILES['file']` before attempting to proceed with the upload, otherwise there's a chance it will fail later on (as it has done) because there isn't a valid file to work with.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: set  upload_max_filesize = 20M and post_max_size = 21M but the file still isnt uploaded

Comment: Maybe these settings didn't take (use phpinfo to verify), maybe the file you are trying to upload is still "too close" to those limits (the whole request will likely be _more_ than the pure initial file size), or maybe some other setting that might factor in is still too low. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184513/1427878

Answer (score 1):

Apache for some reason had php.ini in a different folder (/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini) changed the settings and it works. So if anyone has the same problem check where is your php.ini file, I used phpinfo() function to see which config file was being used

Comment: There are separate php.ini files for command-line PHP and web-based PHP, and of course for each installed PHP version within that. And I think some Linux O/Ses may also store the files in slightly different places, possibly even with redundant copies in other places, if the package maintainers aren't entirely thorough. So yes, you should always use phpinfo() to check what the real configuration is, if you're unsure.